# Using regex to replace everything but a specific line

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace everything that does not match the specified string. This would be I wish I could to a Match or something like that but I am sadly working in a software that only allows me to do regex calls within their replace function

For example, my string will be formatted like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2018 20:51:23 GMT
Server: Apache
x-request-id: eb6cf28d-fad9-42e2-ac3d-4efcf66c5f9b
ETag: 83705a06-4562-4bbd-bcbe-c7643d2d6008
Content-Length: 531
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Robots-Tag: none
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

I need to remove everything that does not match

**ETag: 83705a06-4562-4bbd-bcbe-c7643d2d6008**

I have written some regex that selects **ETag: 83705a06-4562-4bbd-bcbe-c7643d2d6008** that looks like `(ETag: [a-zA-Z\d.-]*)`

And this does select that line, but I need to replace everything but that line. I have read a few post that asked suggested to do the following:

`^(ETag: [a-zA-Z\d.-]*)`

`(?:(ETag: [a-zA-Z\d.-]*))`

`(ETag: [a-zA-Z\d.-]*)[^]`

None of those seemed to work I have a sample of this running on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/44rbb)

Once again, I need to replace everything that does not match **ETag: GUID**. I would appreciate any help in doing this. I am sure I am just missing something small.

Comment: Regex itself doesn't have a negation operator.  `grep` does, by providing a `-v` to grep.  What is your runtime environment?

Comment: @DanFarrell I want to say it is something like VBA, but to be honest I have no idea. Its some weird drag and drop interface. It just has many functions inline with VBA functions so I am assuming they are using the same runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex doesn't really have negation, but usually you can use negative lookaheads:

```regex
^(?!ETag: [a-zA-Z\d.-]*).*$
```

This matches the beginning of a line that can't match `ETag:...`, followed by the rest of the line. You can see how it works in this [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/BAsmeu/1).

Comment: that would be PCRE, but wouldn't be possible with most (all?) other types of regular expressions.  I'm just throwing that out there to provide some clarity if you run into issues.

Comment: This worked... Thank you so much... So I wasn't far off just had to mix and match some more. Thank you so MUCH!

Comment: @DanFarrell It actually is possible with most types of "regular expressions", as you can see from the Demo it also works in Python and Javascript-style regexes. Of course it isn't a "real" regular expression (as in: Chomsky type-3 language) anymore, but basically no modern regex engines support only those.